# How to set reflected property value stored as object?

Tags: c#, oop, recursion, reflection, propertyinfo

I would like to set a value of a property of a reflected object, but I cannot refer to the object itself. I have the property stored as `System.object`- that's all.

```
class Painting
{
   public System.Color PaintingColor;
   {
       get { return m_color; }
       set { m_color = value; }
   }
}
```

Basing on the example - I have an object of type `System.Color`, which is actually a property value of a `Painting` I have created via reflection. I would like to do:

```
object pnt = //initialized with Activator.CreateInstance
pnt.GetType().GetProperty("PaintingColor").SetValue(pnt, Color.Black);
```

However, due to recursion I'm using, I only have:

`object clr = pnt.GetType().GetProperty("PaintingColor").GetValue();`

with no access to `pnt`. Is it possible to change the `clr` so it actually changes the property value of `pnt`? Obviously, `clr = Color.Black` doesn't work.

Comment: I read your question numerous times but I have no idea what your question is; especially the part *due to recursion, I only have...*

Comment: @CodingYoshi in my project i have to use recursion and the limitations come from the arguments of my recursive function

Comment: Why don't you have access to `pnt`? What does your recursive method look like? What's preventing you from passing it?

Comment: @itsme86 The fact that prevents me are nested properties. Let's say I have `Painter:Painting:PaintingColor` and I would like to change `PaintingColor`, having one `Painter`. Passing the `Painter` object isn't enough - I would have to store the whole properties path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are getting in your code is the actual value of the property; not a reference or pointer that you could use to actually assign it.

If the value you got was mutable then you could change properties *on that object* and it would propagate, but that doesn't apply to `System.Color`.

If you really need to do this, I would suggest changing the property to a wrapper around `System.Color` so you can change the internal variable. Generally speaking though, the need to do this indicates you are probably not doing it right.

Comment: I need to set values of nested properties from an external library, so I use the recursion. Let's say I have `Painter:Painting:PaintingColor`. Starting with a painter, I would like to change a painting color. Then, what should I pass in recursion to make it work?

Comment: @NWafel I'm not sure why that is inherently recursive unless you are just trying to look for a `PaintingColor` somewhere in the object graph. Even so you should be able to go one step back up the call stack and set the found property.

Comment: Possibly, I could have longer path of inheritance. However, I guess it's the problem with my recursion - I will think more about it and make it possible to go step back. Then it'll all work, thank you :)